# Problems with concurrency SQL Server 2012 - Table Lock and Unique Index

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, locking

I have the following procedure:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    DECLARE @I_NEW_GUIDE BIGINT

    SELECT @I_NEW_GUIDE = MAX(ID_NUM_CAR) + 1 FROM CAR_GUIDE GR WITH (TABLOCKX) 

    SELECT @I_NEW_GUIDE
COMMIT
```

The procedure generates a sequence, ie simply returns the "last" field ID_NUM_CAR of the CAR_GUIDE table and sum 1.

In a later process this same ID_NUM_CAR will be inserted into the CAR_GUIDE table.

**What's my problem?**

> 1 - ID_NUM_CAR can not be duplicated.
>
> 2 - ID_NUM_CAR can be null.

I tried to use sequence but it did not work well.

My biggest problem is the concurrency of access to this procedure that generates the sequential.

Example: When two processes access the procedure at the same time, they end up getting the same `MAX(ID)`.
ID_NUM_CAR has a unique index to prevent duplicate data.

When these two processes have the same ID_NUM_CAR and they are used for insertion into the CAR_GUIDE table I have an error because unique key.

What is the best way to retrieve the sequence based on the ID_NUM_CAR column?

I've tried using SEQUENCE, TABLOCKX, TABLOCK and HOLDLOCK but it did not work well.

**Sequence**

```
DECLARE @START_SEQ BIGINT = 331, @I_NEW_GUIDE BIGINT

BEGIN
SET @START_SEQ = (SELECT MAX(ID_NUM_CAR) + 1 FROM GUIA_REMESSA);

IF OBJECT_ID('SEQ_ID_NUM_CAR') IS NOT NULL
DROP SEQUENCE [dbo].[SEQ_ID_NUM_CAR]

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = 'CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[SEQ_ID_NUM_CAR] 
 AS [bigint]
 START WITH ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), @START_SEQ)
 + ' INCREMENT BY 1
 MINVALUE 331
 MAXVALUE 999999999
 CACHE'

 EXEC(@SQL) 

 SELECT @I_NEW_GUIDE = NEXT VALUE FOR [SEQ_ID_NUM_CAR]

 SELECT @I_NEW_GUIDE

 END
```

Comment: Why can't you use an identity column?

Comment: The lock is released after the commit. Other processes may get the same value unless you perform the insert in the same transaction. IDENTITY or SEQUENCE should avoid this problem and provide better concurrency. Show us that code that did not work.

Comment: @TabAlleman because the column can null.

Comment: @DanGuzman They can not be in the same transaction, since the insertion involves validation with webService.

Comment: Can you add the `SEQUENCE` code that did not work?

Comment: @DanGuzman added

Comment: @ThamiresCunha, the sequence create script should only be run once when the database is deployed. In the operational code, use `NEXT VALUE FOR` similarly to your code code to get the next value.

Comment: IDENTITY property would solve this using this method: rather than fetching a max value first, I would seed the data first, use SCOPE_IDENTITY() to get the associated ID_NUM_CAR , and then go about my 1) validation with the ws, 2) inserting in to the child table(s), etc. N number of queries grabbing 'MAX' will result in duplicates.

Comment: @DanGuzman I can't create sequence once time with 'STAR WITH' of sequence is using dynamic query

Comment: @ThamiresCunham I must not understand your situation. Why do you need to create the sequence dynamically with a different start value? From where does the start value originate? The 331 hard-coded value would result in the same value every time the script is run.

Comment: Every single roll your own type of identity solution I have ever seen is fraught with issues. Either a sequence or an identity is the way to go here.